# Atributo "clearTaskOnLaunch" no funciona

Tags: android

Lo que necesito básicamente es que cuando el usuario salga del app por A o B motivo al regresar me lleve al Login y no a la pantalla donde se quedó.

Coloco el atributo `clearTaskOnLaunch` en true luego entiendo que el comportamiento deberia de ser que estando en la `activity MainActivity`, `Main2Activity`, `Main3Activity` si yo salgo al home o cambio de app al regresar limpia el `backstack` y se llame al `activity TimeOut` que es quien tiene el atributo, pero este comportamiento no sucede y siempre regresa al `activity` donde se quedó.

Este es mi manifest, no se si deba configuerar algo más para que funcione:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mikemir.sessiontimeout">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <service
            android:name=".Services.SessionService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity android:name=".TimeOut"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Main3Activity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Hola Michael, podrias agregar tu codigo actual, a demas a que te refieres con "no funciona" ¿cual es el comportamiento que tienes actualmente?

Comment: @MichaelEmir espero mi respuesta te ayude, saludos!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es que no funcione **[clearTaskOnLaunch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear)** solo asegura que las Actividades se inicien de tu actividad raíz `TimeOut`.

Si consultas la [documentación](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear) :

> Este atributo es significativo sólo para las actividades que inician
>   una nueva tarea (la actividad raiz); se ignora para todas las demás
>   actividades de la tarea.

Por lo tanto, debe funcionar correctamente de esta forma, la actividad raíz `TimeOut`, inicia las demás actividades :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma no funcionaría correctamente, ya que la actividad raíz, Activity 1, no inicia Activity 3 :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asegura que los intent para abrir las actividades se inicien desde la actividad:

```
 <activity android:name=".TimeOut"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true">
```